# How to convert a list string into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

string type

```
a = " ['a','b','c']"
```

expected list:

```
a
> ['a','b','c']
```

How would I convert a list form in string to a true list?

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @slider: interestingly, I get an error for the OP's input. `ast.literal_eval` does not like that space in front at all: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: @usr2564301 You're right, I see that too. `strip` seems like a good simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the below a try:

`eval(a.strip(' '))`

EDIT:

***eval is evil.*** Please see the link provided by e.doroskevic !!

Comment: eval is evil...

Comment: @ThePineapple lol. i concur! eval is evil!!  I used eval, but I refrained myself from mentioning the words nasa and the moon.